# "suchen" vs. "schnellsuche" for a search feature on a website

Tags: english-to-german, difference

I have typically seen "suchen" and "suche"

[image: suchen]

[image: suchen bar]

but have also ran into "schnellsuche".

[image: schnellsuche]

Is there a time when you would use one over the other? and what are some of the differences in how formal they are?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's merely a matter of preference.  However, **Schnellsuche** means "quick search."

It's hard for me to tell whether in the second example, they mean to use the imperative form of "suchen" or the noun "Suche."  I would guess the noun.  Additionally, should I be making a website in German, I would use "suchen" rather than "Suche".

Comment: that's funny... I perceive "Suche..." as being an imperative. Those soft one like "Vernetz dich mit Freunden."

Answer (score 8):

The word *Schnellsuche* implies that there is (in addition to this "quick search") also a more detailed search function, which allows you to fine-tune your search request, as opposed to the quick search, which performs the search based on default settings.

*Suche* can be both the noun, but also the imperative of the verb ("Search now!"). Both is spelled with a capital "S" here because it is (sort of) the beginning of the sentence. Having the ellipsis suggests that the noun is meant.

You could also use *Suchbegriffe*, which translates to *search terms*, but most common are *Suchen* or *Schnellsuche* (if – as I said – there's a detailed search, too).

Comment: Nice answer... I know of some pages that have both options right under each other. Like... in a series so to speak